# JTAG adapter ULINK-ME and openocd (on ArchLinux)

Tags: arm, archlinux, openocd, cmsis

I installed Openocd from opfficial Arch Linux repositories today and am now trying to use it with my JTAG adapter [ULINK-ME](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulinkme/ulinkme_su_connecting.htm). I found out that ULINK-ME uses CMSIS-DAP debugging firmware. Openocd has CMSIS-DAP drivers and should therefore be able to communicate with my adapter but after I wrote the command below I got an error.

I am connecting ULINK-ME to the board [EA3141](http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/kits/lpc3141_kit.php) which integrates microcontroller LPC3141 - a close relative to LPC3131 for whom I load the configuration file.

```
sudo openocd -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/target/lpc3131.cfg -d3

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.8.0-dev-00175-g8b7acca-dirty (2014-10-14-19:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
User : 13 1 command.c:549 command_print(): debug_level: 3
Debug: 14 1 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /root/.openocd
Debug: 15 1 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/share/openocd/site
Debug: 16 1 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts
Debug: 17 1 configuration.c:86 find_file(): found /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/cmsis-dap.cfg
Debug: 18 1 command.c:145 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_interface cmsis-dap
Debug: 19 2 command.c:145 script_debug(): command - interface ocd_interface cmsis-dap
Debug: 21 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis-dap'...
Debug: 22 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis_dap_vid_pid'...
Debug: 23 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 24 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 25 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 26 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 27 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 28 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 29 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 30 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 31 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Info : 32 2 transport.c:118 allow_transports(): only one transport option; autoselect 'cmsis-dap'
Debug: 33 2 adi_v5_cmsis_dap.c:246 cmsis_dap_select(): CMSIS-ADI: cmsis_dap_select
Debug: 34 2 command.c:404 register_command(): command 'cmsis-dap' is already registered in '<global>' context
Debug: 35 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis-dap'...
Error: 36 7 cmsis_dap_usb.c:175 cmsis_dap_usb_open(): unable to open CMSIS-DAP device
Error: 37 7 adi_v5_cmsis_dap.c:266 cmsis_dap_select(): unable to init CMSIS-DAP driver
Error: 38 7 transport.c:83 transport_select(): Error selecting 'cmsis-dap' as transport
Debug: 39 7 command.c:631 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
User : 40 7 command.c:669 command_run_line(): Runtime Error: /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/cmsis-dap.cfg:7: 
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 58
in procedure 'interface' called at file "/usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/cmsis-dap.cfg", line 7
```

Does anyone know why I get the errors?

---

I allso tried to start it in another way but again it prints errors. A bit difrently this time.

```
sudo openocd -c "interface cmsis-dap" -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/target/lpc3131.cfg -d3

Open On-Chip Debugger 0.8.0-dev-00175-g8b7acca-dirty (2014-10-14-19:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
User : 13 2 command.c:549 command_print(): debug_level: 3
Debug: 14 2 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /root/.openocd
Debug: 15 2 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/share/openocd/site
Debug: 16 2 configuration.c:45 add_script_search_dir(): adding /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts
Debug: 17 2 command.c:145 script_debug(): command - ocd_command ocd_command type ocd_interface cmsis-dap
Debug: 18 2 command.c:145 script_debug(): command - interface ocd_interface cmsis-dap
Debug: 20 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis-dap'...
Debug: 21 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis_dap_vid_pid'...
Debug: 22 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 23 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 24 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 25 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 26 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 27 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 28 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 29 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Debug: 30 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_jtag'...
Info : 31 2 transport.c:118 allow_transports(): only one transport option; autoselect 'cmsis-dap'
Debug: 32 2 adi_v5_cmsis_dap.c:246 cmsis_dap_select(): CMSIS-ADI: cmsis_dap_select
Debug: 33 2 command.c:404 register_command(): command 'cmsis-dap' is already registered in '<global>' context
Debug: 34 2 command.c:369 register_command_handler(): registering 'ocd_cmsis-dap'...
Error: 35 7 cmsis_dap_usb.c:175 cmsis_dap_usb_open(): unable to open CMSIS-DAP device
Error: 36 7 adi_v5_cmsis_dap.c:266 cmsis_dap_select(): unable to init CMSIS-DAP driver
Error: 37 7 transport.c:83 transport_select(): Error selecting 'cmsis-dap' as transport
Debug: 38 7 command.c:631 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
User : 39 7 command.c:669 command_run_line(): in procedure 'interface'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Output of the `sudo lsusb -v command for ULINK-ME is:

```
Bus 005 Device 018: ID c251:2721 Keil Software, Inc.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xc251 Keil Software, Inc.
  idProduct          0x2721
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           4 Keil Software
  iProduct               32 Keil ULINK-ME
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      25
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Because there is no string "CMSIS-DAP" in it I guess it means that I have an older ULINK-ME (bought before 2013) adapter which didn't have CMSIS-DAP firmware. I hope Keil offers some way of flashing CMSIS-DAP to my older ULINK-ME.

---

**SOLUTION:**

I wrote to Keil and they claimed that ULINK-ME's firmware can be updated and it is true. They pointed me to these three links:

[1. - check serial number](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_boot_mode.htm)

[2. - upgrade if Keil uVision hasn't done this by itself in point 1.](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_fw_upgrade.htm)

[3. - manipulate your ULINK-ME even further](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_ctx_debugdrivercfg.htm)

I had to install MDK-ARM v5 on a Windows machine and then click on a very hidden icon (a magic wand) on a toolbar. There under debugging I chose the ULINK2/ME option and it updated my firmware by itself. Now I have a CMSIS-DAP on my ULINK-ME (older model) and I can confirm this with `sudo lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 005 Device 026: ID c251:2723 Keil Software, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xc251 Keil Software, Inc.
  idProduct          0x2723 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Keil Software
  iProduct                2 Keil ULINK-ME CMSIS-DAP
  iSerial                 3 M0489MAE
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              4 CMSIS-DAP
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      33
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I tried to do this using Wine, but it wasn't possible. At least now I don't need Windows any more.

Answer (score 2):

`0.8.0-dev-00175-g8b7acca-dirty`
This does not look like an official OpenOCD. Where did you get it ?

Note: Your version should say `0.9.0` and definitely not `'dirty'`.

Your version of OpenOCD might have problems with CMSIS-DAP.
I highly recommend you to clone the current HEAD from here:

```
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/openocd/code openocd
```

(remember to do `./bootstrap`, before you `./configure ...` after cloning)

-Or download from [Freddie Chopin's site](http://www.freddiechopin.info/en/download/category/10-openocd-dev) if you're running it under Windows.

`sudo openocd`
Something is wrong here too. You should not have to 'sudo' each time you want to use OpenOCD.

Anyway, you should be able to use JTAG (LPC3141 seems to be too old to support SWD).

Comment: This is a problem because I have to install openocd using Archlinux official repositories. Archlinux official repositories are probably out of date.

Comment: The 'officials' often pick a version, which has a problem (for some reason). If it's possible for you to build it yourself, I'll be happy to guide you through it. But since rebuilding it would take some time, you might want to try using SWD first; this should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: It is meaningless because my JTAG adapter has no CMSIS-DAP firmware. :) I bought myself a better JTAG adapter (J-link EDU).

Comment: If it has no CMSIS-DAP firmware, then use JTAG, as I just had a look on the datasheet; the LPC3141 seem to be too old to have SWD support. JTAG is the `transport` to use then.

Comment: OpenOCD in Arch's repositories is either vanilla 0.8.0 or you can build one yourself (using current git HEAD) when you use a package from AUR...

Comment: @Freddie - try looking at the OpenOCD build date. It doesn't make sense to me that the version is 0.8.0 - why would they wait a year and then build an old unofficial (dirty) version ?

Comment: I know, but believe me that official package is clean 0.8.0, and in AUR you can build whatever you want from git... For example here's a binary I built a few days ago using package from AUR - `Open On-Chip Debugger 0.9.0-dev-00186-g30203b3 (2014-11-07-11:55)`.

Comment: I found the solution to updating ULINK-ME and use CMSIS-DAP with it, but it won't work with openocd...

Comment: I am positive that OpenOCD 0.8.0 does not support CMSIS-DAP. Did you try the current repository HEAD (v0.9.0) ?